# Are all three conditions for the Leibniz criterion needed?

Tags: convergence-divergence

I'm trying to convince myself that all three conditions

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ is null sequence}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
(|a_n|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ is monotonically decreasing}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
a_n \text{ has alternating signs}
\end{equation}

of the Leibniz criterion are needed by finding examples where one condition is violated and $\sum a_n$ doesn't exist.

For (1), I've got $a_n = (-1)^n$ (meets (2) and (3) but $\sum (-1)^n$ doesn't exist).

For (3), I've got $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n}$ (meets (1) and (2) but $\sum \dfrac{1}{n}$ doesn't exist).

But I can't find a sequence that meets (1) and (3) but not (2) so that $\sum a_n$ diverges. I'm pretty sure that it needs to contain a $(-x)^n$ part of some sort to meet (3) but as soon as I make it small enough to be a null sequence (e.g. by dividing by $n$) the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: interleave a convergent series of negative terms with a divergent series of positive terms.

Comment: Could you give an additional hint on interleave? Could the alternating sign come from adding something and then substracting something again?

Comment: Interleave = ripple shuffle = dovetail = make alternate choices from the positive terms and the negative terms (no additions or subtractions required).

Comment: That's so simple! I didn't even consider that. It's almost like cheating! :)
Thank you very much